# How to mock internal val variableName:Interface=Class using mockk in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, junit, mockk

I am using one val like  `internal val variableName:Interface=Class` when I am writing the unit test for the class I am mocking the variable using mockk. While running the test getting the below error

Code

```
@VisibleForTesting(otherwise = VisibleForTesting.PRIVATE)
internal val vehicleName: IVehicleNames = VehicleNameManager
```

Test Code

```
@RelaxedMockK
private lateinit var vehicleName: IVehicleNames
```

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Can any one tell me how I call resolve this problem

I already tried mockkobject

Comment: The problem does not become clear from the question. Please provide minimal example classes and interfaces you want to mock. Also, please provide the code in your test class how you try to define your mock. Moreover, does the `ExceptionInInitializerError` have any error message describing the error that occurred?

Comment: Is there no error message to the `ExceptionInInitializerError`? Do you inject that mock into another class? If so, please show how you do it.